# Make Tab a scrollbar and show only 3 out of 6 tabs

Tags: android, tabs, scrollview, android-tabhost

Im trying to set my tabs as a scrollbar. I have 6 tabs but want to show 3 in the UI. How do I set the scrollbar view in this format? If it even possible to set it like this?

Tab Bar is based on androids developer page.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

       <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java file

```
package developers.tab;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class AndroidDevelopersTabActivity extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WorkoutActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("workouts").setIndicator("Workout",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_workout))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ExcerciseActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("excercises").setIndicator("Excercises",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ProgramsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("programs").setIndicator("Programs",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LogActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("mealplans").setIndicator("Meal Plans",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BodyMActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("bodymeasurements").setIndicator("Body Measurements",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MealPlanActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("mealplan").setIndicator("Meal Plan",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why couldn't you just make the visiblity of unwanted tabs "GONE"?

You can make the side tabs GONE or VISIBLE when scrolling from side to side.

By `view.setVisibility=GONE;` or `view.setVisibility=VISIBLE;`

If you do viewA GONE, it will take no place. All other views behave themselves as if viewA didn't exist. Listen to scrolling and when there is place for showing right tabs, show them, and hide the left ones. And vice versa.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to be able to access the "missing" tabs by scrolling the tabs to the side.

Comment: He can make the side tabs GONE or VISIBLE when scrolling from side to side.

Comment: Hey Gangnus. how do i do this?

Comment: i still want all 6 tabs to be accesible if the user scrolls left or right